# How does gerrit stand in way of Git repository

Tags: git, gerrit

I've been working on gerrit for quite some time now. However, I am not really sure how Gerrit prevents, or rather enforces a review before remote commit. In other words, how does Gerrit ensure that no unreviewed code should go to repo (exceptional cases of bypasssing can be neglected for the time being).
Can someone please throw more light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the [way Gerrit is supposed to work](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9.1/intro-quick.html), a developper should only see the Gerrit repo.

[image: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9.1/images/intro-quick-central-gerrit.png]

Then, Gerrit, through its [access controls](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9.1/access-control.html), can grant some developers the right to push directly to the authoritative repository.

> Gerrit is deployed in place of this central repository and adds an additional concept, a store of pending changes.
>   **Everyone still fetches from the authoritative repository but instead of pushing back to it, they push to this pending changes location**.
>   **A change can only be submitted into the authoritative repository and become an accepted part of the project once the change has been reviewed and approved**.

Comment: The CI Build Server will fetch the pending changes and try to verify them, build, unit test etc.